# how does facebook select the picture when implementing a "like" feature with multiple og:image

Tags: image, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-sharer

Here's what I'm trying to do : I have about 20 `og:image` in meta tags on one page, and on this page I have both a like button AND a share button (the deprecated one). I need all the 20 `og:image` for the share feature, and I want Facebook to pick a particular image when building the popup window (or "flyout"), which will also be the image displayed on a facebook wall after publishing.

Currently, the picture in the popup window is the first `og:image`, but when I publish and go on my facebook wall, facebook picked another picture to display (the 7th of the `og:image` list, to be more precise).

I got nearly the same problem on the share feature, I can't obtain the first `og:image` to be the first thumbnail of the available thumbnails list. The 7th image in `og:image` list is always the first thumbnail proposed.

Anyone knows the picking algorithm of Facebook or something? I've been searching everywhere and I can't find a single clue on this.

I tried to swap images but I have to avoid putting the same image twice (1st and 7th). I really need some help.

Thank you

Comment: Actually, the popup should give you the "liker" to choose which of the 20 photos to use in their popup. That choice should be used in the post, not some random one.  Does this happen with one page or all pages that have multiple photos specified?

Comment: The (deprecated) share button, and the (not deprecated) share functionality on facebook.com itself allow you to choose the image. The Like button does not, it's a single click to perform the 'like' + optional comment box which updates the story with your comment if submitted

Comment: Yes, I have been able to duplicate this issue too.  @user you should log this as an enhancement request for the like plugin. http://developers.facebook.com/bugs  Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's supposed to be random - regardless, if you only want one image, just use one og:url tag